# Sampling conditions from different tables yii2

Tags: yii2

There is two models `Order` and `OrderDeliveryData`. They are related

```
public function getOrderDeliveryData(){
    return $this->hasOne(OrderDeliveryData::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

How could doing something like this in Search model(now an error)?

```
$query = Order::find()->andWhere(['orderDeliveryData.order_delivery_data_courierId' => ("51")])
        ->andWhere(['order_status' => ("send")]);
```

Comment: You want to select orders which has order_status send and `orderDeliveryData.order_delivery_data_courierId` is 51 or you want to select all orders which has `order_status` =>  `send` and corresponding `orderDeliveryData`s, which has `order_delivery_data_courierId = 51`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = Order::find()->with(['orderDeliveryData' => function($query){
        $query->where([ 'order_delivery_data_courierId' => '51' ]);
    }])->where(['order_status' => "send"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write join or `joinWith` on `OrderDeliveryData` model to be able to use its columns in where.

```
$query = Order::find()
          ->joinWith(['orderDeliveryData'])
          ->andWhere([OrderDeliveryData::tablename().'.order_delivery_data_courierId' => "51"])
    ->andWhere(['order_status' => ("send")]);
```